# Writing lists of values to a csv file in different columns using Python

Tags: excel, list, csv, multiple-columns

I need help with writing values to a csv file.

I have 4 lists of values that I would like to write to a csv file, but not in a normal way. I mean, usually the csv module write the values in the same row, but this time I would like to write the values of the lists in different columns, I mean one column and different rows for every list. In this way, all the list 1 data would be in the column A of Excel, all the list 2 data would be in the column B of excel, and so on. Now I was trying a lot of commands and I half did it, but not at all.

My list's names are: It_5minute, Iiso_5min, IHDKR_5min and Iperez_5min.

My actual commands:

```
with open('Test.csv', 'w') as f:
    w = csv.writer(f)
    for row in zip(It_5minute, Iiso_5min, IHDKR_5min,Iperez_5min):
        w.writerow(row)
```

With these commands I get the list values in the same column (instead of every list in a different column), each value separated by comma. I have attached an Excel image to clarify the problem. I want each list in a separated column, to be able of do operations with the data in an easy way. Can anybody help me? Thank you very much.

PD: Would be nice to write the name of each list at the top of every column, too.

[image]

Comment: I believe it has nothing to do with python or csv but with the excel.

Comment: You could use a different delimiter, like a space or tabs, and see if Excel plays nicely with the import.

Comment: I tried with a space between the values but was I still got the same. All the values in the same column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for the fact change with `open('Test.csv', 'w') as f:` to `with open('Test.csv', 'wb') as f:` as csv's are binary.

State the delimiter to use clearly *(in this case a comma)* and whether or not to use [quoting](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.QUOTE_ALL) just in case *(optional)*

```
with open('Test.csv', 'wb') as f:
    w = csv.writer(f,delimiter=',', quoting = csv.QUOTE_ALL) #you can replace the delimiter for whatever that suits you
    for row in zip(It_5minute, Iiso_5min, IHDKR_5min,Iperez_5min):
        w.writerow(row)
```

In case this doesn't work, you have to manually state the delimiter in the excel text import wizard. **You can read how to [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/import-or-export-text-txt-or-csv-files-HP010342598.aspx)**

## Common Delimiters:

Tab = `'\t'`

semicolon = `';'`

comma = `','`

space = `' '`

*eg: comma selected as the delimiter*

[image]

Comment: I don't know why but Python doesn't accept 'with open('Test.csv', 'wb') as f:', I receive the following error: TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface...

Doing it manually in Excel as you said works perfectly. Thank you very much for answering!